# How to concatenate variable with slash as a new string

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have the following bash code:

```
FULLSTR="/FOO/BAR/QUX"
IFS=/
ARY=($FULLSTR)
```

What I want to do is to concatenate the 2nd and 3rd element of `ARY` with 
`/` and assigned it into a variable. The end result I hope to get is `/BAR/QUX`.

But why this doesn't work:

```
NSTR=/${ARY[2]}/${ARY[3]}
echo $NSTR
```

It produces:

```
 BAR QUX
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: And if you quote your variables?  For example, `NSTR="/${ARY[2]}/${ARY[3]}"; echo "$NSTR"`?  Always quote your variables, unless you know precisely why you don't want to.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in your `echo $NSTR` command: `IFS` is still set to `/`, so when `$NSTR` undergoes word-splitting and file-name expansion, the stuff on either side of a `/` becomes separate arguments to `echo`.

To fix this, I recommend finding a better way to set `ARY` to begin with, rather than starting with `$FULLSTR`. Parameter-expansions such as `$FULLSTR` should essentially *always* be quoted, because you essentially *never* want word-splitting and filename-expansion. (In your case you do want the word-splitting . . . but not the filename-expansion.)

If that's not an option — if your only way to set `ARY` is by splitting `$FULLSTR` — then you can write something like this:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=/
ARY=($FULLSTR)
IFS="$OLDIFS"

NSTR="/${ARY[2]}/${ARY[3]}"
echo "$NSTR"
```

Or, better yet, you can set `NSTR` directly based on `$FULLSTR`, and avoid `ARY` except when you have no choice:

```
NSTR="/${FULLSTR#/*/}"
echo "$NSTR"
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to concatenate and yes cut!

```
FULLSTR="/FOO/BAR/QUX"

echo ${FULLSTR#/FOO}
```

Output:

```
/BAR/QUX
```

so has your result !!